# Styling and collapsing an unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an unordered list that I would like to style to expand and collapse on the parent but not on its children.  For lack of a better term this lists only has children but no grandchildren so there is no need to expand or collapse to that level.

Currently with this example the parent collapses and expands when I click on the arrow or the text which is exactly the behavior I want.  However when one of the children's checkboxes is clicked this also causes the parent to collapse. This is not the desired effect.  Also, notice the difference in behavior when selecting the text of the checkbox versus the checkbox itself.  I actually want to kickoff some additional javascript when the checkbox is checked (to include the label) which I will need to add later.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#main li ul').hide();
    $('#colorsec').find('UL').show();
    $('#coldiv li').click(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle("fast");
        $('.colopen, .colclosed').toggleClass('colopen colclosed');
    });
    $('#proddiv li').click(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle("fast");
        $('.prodopen, .prodclosed').toggleClass('prodopen prodclosed');
    });
    $('#graindiv li').click(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle("fast");
        $('.grainopen, .grainclosed').toggleClass('grainopen grainclosed');
    });
    $('#findiv li').click(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle("fast");
        $('.finopen, .finclosed').toggleClass('finopen finclosed');
    });
});
```

```css
  #page-wrap ul li ul {
    display: none;
  }
  /* This removes the defaul image for the list item */
  #page-wrap > ul > li {
    list-style: none;
  }
  /* This removes the image we put on the list item above */
  #sublists {
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: -2em;
  }
  #main {
    font-family: HelveticaNeueLT-Medium, Museo-500, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  .custom-checked {
    font-family: HelveticaNeueLT-Light, Museo-500, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  #main {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #colorsec.colopen {
    list-style-image: url('http://s6.postimg.org/3ps5fdti5/Up_Arrow.jpg');
  }
  #colorsec.colclosed {
    list-style-image: url('http://s6.postimage.org/53jsaosrh/Down_Arrow.jpg');
  }
  #productsec.prodopen {
    list-style-image: url('http://s6.postimg.org/3ps5fdti5/Up_Arrow.jpg');
  }
  #productsec.prodclosed {
    list-style-image: url('http://s6.postimage.org/53jsaosrh/Down_Arrow.jpg');
  }
  #grainsec.grainopen {
    list-style-image: url('http://s6.postimg.org/3ps5fdti5/Up_Arrow.jpg');
  }
  #grainsec.grainclosed {
    list-style-image: url('http://s6.postimage.org/53jsaosrh/Down_Arrow.jpg');
  }
  #finsec.finopen {
    list-style-image: url('http://s6.postimg.org/3ps5fdti5/Up_Arrow.jpg');
  }
  #finsec.finclosed {
    list-style-image: url('http://s6.postimage.org/53jsaosrh/Down_Arrow.jpg');
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-wrap">
    <ul id="main">
        <div id="coldiv">
            <li id="colorsec" class="colopen">Color
                <ul id="sublists">
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Red' id='Red' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Red' class='custom-checked'>Red</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Orange' id='Orange' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Orange' class='custom-checked'>Orange</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Brown' id='Brown' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Brown' class='custom-checked'>Brown</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Beige' id='Beige' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Beige' class='custom-checked'>Beige</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='White' id='White' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='White' class='custom-checked'>White</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Off_White' id='Off_White' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Off_White' class='custom-checked'>Off White</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Pink' id='Pink' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Pink' class='custom-checked'>Pink</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Purple' id='Purple' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Purple' class='custom-checked'>Purple</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Grey' id='Grey' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Grey' class='custom-checked'>Grey</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Black' id='Black' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Black' class='custom-checked'>Black</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Blue' id='Blue' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Blue' class='custom-checked'>Blue</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Green' id='Green' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Green' class='custom-checked'>Green</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Yellow' id='Yellow' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Yellow' class='custom-checked'>Yellow</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
        <div id="proddiv">
            <li id="productsec" class="prodclosed">Product
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Andes</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Sabrina</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Volo</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Ducale</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Marissa</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
        <div id="graindiv">
            <li id="grainsec" class="grainclosed">Grain
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Raised</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Full</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Flat</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Pronounced</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Corrected</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
        <div id="findiv">
            <li id="finsec" class="finclosed">Finish
                <ul>
                    <li><span>None</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Light</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Light Waxy</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Pebble</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Heavy</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fsn0eo06/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stopPropagation` to prevent unwanted behavior. It'll still allow you to add behaviors on these elements if needed. See:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#main li ul').hide();
    $('#colorsec').find('UL').show();
    $('#coldiv li').click(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle("fast");
        $('.colopen, .colclosed').toggleClass('colopen colclosed');
    });
    $('#proddiv li').click(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle("fast");
        $('.prodopen, .prodclosed').toggleClass('prodopen prodclosed');
    });
    $('#graindiv li').click(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle("fast");
        $('.grainopen, .grainclosed').toggleClass('grainopen grainclosed');
    });
    $('#findiv li').click(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle("fast");
        $('.finopen, .finclosed').toggleClass('finopen finclosed');
    });
  $('input, label, li span').click(function(e){
                e.stopPropagation()
            });
});
```

```css
#page-wrap ul li ul {
    display: none;
  }
  /* This removes the defaul image for the list item */
  #page-wrap > ul > li {
    list-style: none;
  }
  /* This removes the image we put on the list item above */
  #sublists {
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: -2em;
  }
  #main {
    font-family: HelveticaNeueLT-Medium, Museo-500, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  .custom-checked {
    font-family: HelveticaNeueLT-Light, Museo-500, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  #main {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #colorsec.colopen {
    list-style-image: url('http://s6.postimg.org/3ps5fdti5/Up_Arrow.jpg');
  }
  #colorsec.colclosed {
    list-style-image: url('http://s6.postimage.org/53jsaosrh/Down_Arrow.jpg');
  }
  #productsec.prodopen {
    list-style-image: url('http://s6.postimg.org/3ps5fdti5/Up_Arrow.jpg');
  }
  #productsec.prodclosed {
    list-style-image: url('http://s6.postimage.org/53jsaosrh/Down_Arrow.jpg');
  }
  #grainsec.grainopen {
    list-style-image: url('http://s6.postimg.org/3ps5fdti5/Up_Arrow.jpg');
  }
  #grainsec.grainclosed {
    list-style-image: url('http://s6.postimage.org/53jsaosrh/Down_Arrow.jpg');
  }
  #finsec.finopen {
    list-style-image: url('http://s6.postimg.org/3ps5fdti5/Up_Arrow.jpg');
  }
  #finsec.finclosed {
    list-style-image: url('http://s6.postimage.org/53jsaosrh/Down_Arrow.jpg');
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-wrap">
    <ul id="main">
        <div id="coldiv">
            <li id="colorsec" class="colopen">Color
                <ul id="sublists">
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Red' id='Red' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Red' class='custom-checked'>Red</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Orange' id='Orange' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Orange' class='custom-checked'>Orange</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Brown' id='Brown' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Brown' class='custom-checked'>Brown</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Beige' id='Beige' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Beige' class='custom-checked'>Beige</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='White' id='White' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='White' class='custom-checked'>White</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Off_White' id='Off_White' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Off_White' class='custom-checked'>Off White</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Pink' id='Pink' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Pink' class='custom-checked'>Pink</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Purple' id='Purple' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Purple' class='custom-checked'>Purple</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Grey' id='Grey' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Grey' class='custom-checked'>Grey</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Black' id='Black' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Black' class='custom-checked'>Black</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Blue' id='Blue' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Blue' class='custom-checked'>Blue</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Green' id='Green' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Green' class='custom-checked'>Green</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Yellow' id='Yellow' class='color_cb' checked>
                        <label for='Yellow' class='custom-checked'>Yellow</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
        <div id="proddiv">
            <li id="productsec" class="prodclosed">Product
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Andes</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Sabrina</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Volo</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Ducale</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Marissa</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
        <div id="graindiv">
            <li id="grainsec" class="grainclosed">Grain
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Raised</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Full</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Flat</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Pronounced</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Corrected</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
        <div id="findiv">
            <li id="finsec" class="finclosed">Finish
                <ul>
                    <li><span>None</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Light</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Light Waxy</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Pebble</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Heavy</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow.  How completely simple.  Thank you so much!